# MySql query that aggregate and separe with comma

Tags: mysql

I need to do a query that return all my contact name separeted by comma's when they belong the same Group. I know how to do this in SQL Server using `STUFF` function, but how can I do the same in MySQL ?

**Table: Group**

```
Group_Id   Description
1          New Group
2          Birthday
```

**Table: Contacts**

```
ID         Name       Surname       Group_Id
1          Charlan    Alves         1
2          Lucas      Germano       2
3          Junior     dos Santos    1
```

**What I Expect**

```
Group_Id   Name
1          Charlan Alves, Junior dos Santos
2          Lucas Germano
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT 
  Group_Id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Name, ' ', Surname)) AS group_name 
FROM 
  Contacts 
GROUP BY 
  Group_Id
```

Note, that default separator is `,` (without space after comma). You may wish to add space after comma by specifying `SEPARATOR ', '`